# ComboBox not showing its content in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable

I want to show a Combobox in a JTable. For the JTable I use a TableModel. I have succeded to show the Combobox (not its toString()). The problem is I can't view its content. The combobox must be not editable. I have read many tutorial but I haven't found one with TableModel. I found this code :

```
 JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
    comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
    comboBox.addItem("Knitting");
    comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
    comboBox.addItem("Pool");
    comboBox.addItem("None of the above");
    sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

    //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
            new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
    sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
}
```

I can't use it for two reason. The content of my Combobox is not the same and they don't use a TableModel. Here's my code :

public class TProfModel extends DefaultTableModel implements TableModel {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String[] names = { "Nom", "Prénom", "Matière", "Classes" };
private Model model;

public TProfModel(Model model){
    this.model = model;
    fireTableDataChanged();
}


public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
    return getValueAt(0,col).getClass();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return names.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return names[col];
}

public int getRowCount() {
    if(model != null)
        return model.getProfs().size();
    return 0;
}

public Object getValueAt(int line, int col) {

    switch (col) {
    case 0:
        return model.getProfs().get(line).getNom();
    case 1:
        return model.getProfs().get(line).getPrenom();
    case 2:
        return model.getProfs().get(line).getMatiere();
    case 3:
        return getClasses(line);
    }
    return null;
}

private JComboBox<String> getClasses(int line) {
    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    for(String classe : model.getProfs().get(line).getClasses())
        comboBox.addItem(classe);
    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    return comboBox;
}


public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    if(arg1 == 3)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object object, int line, int col) {
    switch (col) {
    case 0:
        model.getProfs().get(line).setNom((String) object);
        break;
    case 1:
        model.getProfs().get(line).setPrenom((String) object);
        break;
    case 2:
        model.getProfs().get(line).setMatiere((String) object);
    }
    model.writeData();
}
```

}

Comment: Don't return a component from the model.  It's the responsibility of the editor and renderer to interpret how best to display the supplied value from the model

Comment: And how to do that? I have created a class that implements TableCellRenderer but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Return the value for the given row for that column as an object that your editor can use when `setSelectedValue` is called against it, in this case, that would a `String` value...

Comment: I don't see what do you mean. I have changed my code and the problem is how I set the editor. I must set for the JTable but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the getCellEditor(...) method to return a different editor. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<TableCellEditor> editors = new ArrayList<TableCellEditor>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editors to be used for each row

        String[] items1 = { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( items1 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce1 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
        editors.add( dce1 );

        String[] items2 = { "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox2 = new JComboBox<String>( items2 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce2 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox2 );
        editors.add( dce2 );

        String[] items3 = { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox3 = new JComboBox<String>( items3 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce3 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox3 );
        editors.add( dce3 );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                    return editors.get(row);
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );

    }
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could write a `TableCellEditor` which was capable of extract the values for the given row and the currently selected value - saving the need to implement your own `JTable`...as another option...

Comment: Thanks both of you. That what I have did

Answer (score 3):

The responsibility of a model is to provide data, nothing else.  It's the responsibility of the editors and renderers to interrupt that data and best decide how it should be displayed.

The value that is passed to the editor is the result of `getValueAt`, which in the case of the following example, is nothing more than a `String`, but because the `JComboBox` has been populated with `String` values, this will provide the editor with the capability to find a match for the value (if a valid match exists).

All you need to do is ensure that the editor/renderer knows how to handle the data coming from the model...

[image: TableEditor][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TabelEditorExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TabelEditorExample();
    }

    public TabelEditorExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ShoppingListModel model = new ShoppingListModel();
                model.addEntry(new ShoppingEntry(0, null));
                model.addEntry(new ShoppingEntry(0, null));
                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new String[]{
                    "Apples",
                    "Bananas",
                    "Pears",
                    "Ice-Cream",
                    "World Domination",
                });
                table.
                        getColumnModel().
                        getColumn(1).
                        setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cb));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ShoppingListModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<ShoppingEntry> shoppingEntries;

        public ShoppingListModel() {
            shoppingEntries = new ArrayList<ShoppingEntry>(25);
        }

        public void addEntry(ShoppingEntry entry) {
            shoppingEntries.add(entry);
            fireTableRowsInserted(shoppingEntries.size() - 1, shoppingEntries.size() - 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return shoppingEntries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return column == 0 ? "Qty" : "Item";
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 0 ? Integer.class : String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = shoppingEntries.get(rowIndex).getQty();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = shoppingEntries.get(rowIndex).getItem();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            ShoppingEntry entry = shoppingEntries.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    int qty = 0;
                    if (aValue instanceof String) {
                        qty = Integer.parseInt(aValue.toString());
                    } else if (aValue instanceof Integer) {
                        qty = (Integer)aValue;
                    }
                    entry.setQty(qty);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    entry.setItem(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
                    break;
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

    }

    public class ShoppingEntry {

        private int qty;
        private String item;

        public ShoppingEntry(int qty, String item) {
            this.qty = qty;
            this.item = item;
        }

        public String getItem() {
            return item;
        }

        public int getQty() {
            return qty;
        }

        public void setItem(String item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        public void setQty(int qty) {
            this.qty = qty;
        }

    }

}
```

You also need to override `setValueAt` in you `TableModel` and update it so it updates the values in your supplied model.

Comment: In your example you have fixed the values of cb. In my case each comboBox has its own values.

Comment: Okay, how do you determine what values are loaded into the combo box each time?

Comment: I have an object that have first name last name and an array of String. in my JTable I show the first name, last name and the array of String in comboBox.

Comment: How do you know what the selected value is for the given row?